# My daughter is refusing baby apron before eating

Tags: development

She is one and half year old now. And we want her to get used to apron because soon she will start eating her own completely. But whenever we put this apron it annoys my daughther a lot. And she rejects eating just cries until she is manage to take it off.

We are even making small plays like her mum is putting it on and I putting it on.

If we take the baby apron off than she is all happy again. And eating but whenever she tries to eat herself than her clothes are just being extremely messy and than we are needing to change cloths and even sometimes wash her.

I believe the right behavior for she to understand that she needs to put it on. Or maybe I should surrender and not let her cry too much. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Is she tactile defensive (that is, dislikes something tied around her neck)? Have you tried a smock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There likely is something about the one(s) you have she dislikes.  There are lots of options.  One that I love is to take a fleece sleeper they outgrew & put it on them backward.  Fleece is decently wet resistant, most things will just run off instead of soak through, and it's never stained for me in 3 kids, so the sleeper is still usable after they outgrow eating in it.  They usually have a flap at top of neck that snaps across, that is how I affix it & it's comfy.  It may not be super fashionable, but it's something that works & if you already own it, it's free.

Another easy no argue option is to remove the clothing.  Lots of children eat this way, especially when self feeding.  It save tremendously on time with laundry & clean up.

Personally I would try something like this before trying to force an issue.  Children have preferences just like we do.  They are human beings.  They deserve respect.  They are not set out to fight you on all things, they push back when they are not happy.  Typically speaking, most things you can work around.  The only time you need to dig in & make them do what you want are things like buckling into a car seat, safety, etc.  I never argue with my kids when it's unwarranted.  There is no need.  You want them to be happy too.  If we want to teach our children to be cooperative with us, then we also have to show that we cooperate with them when we are able to.  You can force compliance, but then you get it begrudgingly and because they have to, not out of any desire to please you & work with you.

It is very very possible she truly doesn't like this style.  My one son has a mild sensory process issue.  One of the first ways I saw it was about this age (he was very verbal) and if his shirts had elastic at cuffs he would roll around crying on the floor screaming "I'm locked".  Tons of parents told me to just ignore it & leave the clothing on him (it had gotten cool out, so he hadn't worn long sleeves in a while).  Instead I cut all the elastic out of cuffs & we went on with life.  I didn't know then that he has this issue, but I am glad I opted to accommodate his upset.  Imagine if I had instead forced him to wear that?  Sensory issues operate within a given person as an obvious abrasive irritant the whole time they experience it. I could have gotten him to wear it, but then his whole mood & attitude would have been impacted as he would be trying to *cope* with these cuffs all day & for what?  It was easy (although not fashionable) to cut them.  And despite being very verbal, he couldn't tell me how upsetting they were.  All he could manage was "I'm locked".

Answer (score 2):

whether smock, apron, or bib, obviously you need her to wear something over her clothes when she eats. don't surrender. if you do, she'll learn that she can get her way with you by just crying and carrying on. trust me, you don't want to go down *that* road.

perhaps have a relative or close friend put the smock on her, and  instruct the relative or friend  not to remove it under any circumstances. have the relative or friend feed her while she's wearing the smock. if that's successful, you'll know that the child has manipulated you.

you can win this battle! no one likes listening to their child cry, but sometimes - and I think this is one of those times- it works to the benefit of all concerned. best of luck! hang in there.

Comment: ... or just take all the clothes off... or change the clothing after eating. You don't *have* to force them to do anything.